Filter/selecting features in layer in qgis by grouping after one column and only taking the max value of each group
Lets say there is a layer like this in qgis

which can be copy pasted from this geojson:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "test",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "class": "a", "date": "2024-05-15" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -0.531598513011152, 0.509293680297398 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "class": "a", "date": "2024-05-13" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.105328376703842, 0.144981412639405 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "class": "b", "date": "2024-05-10" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.043370508054523, 0.350681536555142 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "class": "b", "date": "2024-05-06" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -0.216852540272615, 0.437422552664188 ] } }
]
}

Now for each group in the column class (which are a and b) I want to only obtain the rows (be it in a filter or by selecting in qgis) that have the oldest date. In that case it would resolve to a layer/selection with only two rows. One for class aand one for class b.
In a scripting language it would know what to do more or less. But is that possible in qgis-expression (and maybe without using some kind of sql)?

You should be able to use this:
"date" = to_date(
    aggregate(@layer,'max',"date",filter:="class"=attribute(@parent,'class'))
)

The aggregate returns the max(date) grouped by class.
I needed to use to_date as the aggregate was returning a datetime, despite the data all being in date format

thanks so much, it works perfecty:) Just a quick question. What does the @parent-variable refer to exactly?

Expressions run once for every feature. @parent refers to the source feature (see https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) - so the aggregate expression ('max') is using all of the features that have the same 'class' as the original feature. This is a powerful tool, and variations of it are useful for solving many complex expression problems in QGIS.
